# Error installing Heroku Toolbelt

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Tried to install Heroku Toolbelt but now I get a `Gem:LoadError` error when trying to issue any heroku command.

> $ heroku -v
>
> /Users/xyz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in
>   `to_specs': Could not find heroku (>= 0) amongst [...]
>   (Gem::LoadError)
>
> $ which heroku
>
> /Users/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/heroku

It seems it's still seeking the gem, but I already uninstalled it. How can I fix this?

(OSX Mountain Lion)

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the issue, but if it is just that the heroku gem is not installed/missing try:

```
$ gem install heroku
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues initially with ROR on Windows/OS X.(Everyone suggested me to move to LINUX/UNIX)

Rather than installing the Heroku Toolbet (which breaks ruby and rails which is already installed) install the heroku gem along with foreman gem.

```
gem install heroku

gem install foreman
```

Then you can use it easily.